# Interactive polygon shapes

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, svg.js

I have some coordinate points like
[0, 0],[30, 0],[30, 20],[60, 20],[60, 40],[0, 40],[0, 0]

Taking these points as input, need to generate shapes with corners clickable.
The edges overlap over each other.On first mouse click , first segment goes over second.On second click , second segment goes over first and on third click it gives a mitre effect.

[Possible Polygon interaction effects][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok0iM.png

Can I place a rectangle with opacity 0 at the corners for click detection , but the problem is how do I detect the exact position to place the rectangle at corners.

Secondly, what is the best to convert these points as lines or paths?.
The lines generated should be thick enough but not through strokewidth.

I have tried paths before with strokewidth so line join mitre has no effect.
Any suggestions please.

**Sample code with lines and rectangles placed at corners, it didn't give me perfect results may be because of stroke width :**

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="700" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" viewBox="-100 -20 350 200"><defs id="SvgjsDefs1002"></defs><g id="SvgjsG1008" transform="matrix(2.5,0,0,2.5,0,0)"><line id="SvgjsLine1009" x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#ffdc0b" stroke-width="4"></line><line id="SvgjsLine1010" x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="20" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#002438" stroke-width="4"></line><line id="SvgjsLine1011" x1="30" y1="20" x2="60" y2="20" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#9b56bb" stroke-width="4"></line><line id="SvgjsLine1012" x1="60" y1="20" x2="60" y2="40" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#c6c7e2" stroke-width="4"></line><line id="SvgjsLine1013" x1="60" y1="40" x2="0" y2="40" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#318700" stroke-width="4"></line><line id="SvgjsLine1014" x1="0" y1="40" x2="0" y2="0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke="#fe854f" stroke-width="4"></line>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="30" y="0"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="30" y="20"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="60" y="20"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="60" y="40"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="0" y="40"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="0" y="0"></rect></g></svg>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use canvas for that task, SVG is good for static icons, but it is hard to make them interactive. It is high chance you will have problems in different browsers especially safari and IE.

Comment: I need to generate multiple shapes from these coordinates data coming from JSON.

Comment: You can 100% do it with canvas.

Comment: Can you show me a small sample, very new to SVG and Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are asking: in order to draw the corner rects I'm using the bounding pox of every path. Two of them are overlapping: the first one and the last one. But this doesn't matter since you need mouse interaction.  One is missing. this can be drawn by using the bounding box of the group containing your paths.

For mouse interaction I'm using `cursor: pointer;`for every corner.

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let pathsRy = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("path"));

let rectsRy = [];

pathsRy.forEach(p => {
  let pbbox = p.getBBox();
  rectsRy.push(
    drawRect(
      {
        x: pbbox.x,
        y: pbbox.y,
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
        class: "corner"
      },
      svg
    )
  );
});

let gbbox = group.getBBox();
rectsRy.push(
  drawRect(
    {
      x: gbbox.x + gbbox.width - 5,
      y: gbbox.y + gbbox.height - 5,
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      class: "corner"
    },
    svg
  )
);

function drawRect(o, parent) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "rect");
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}
```

```css
.corner {
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 70 70" width="200" >
<g id="group">  
  <path d="M0,0 L30,0 25,5 5,5z" /> 
           
  <path d="M30,0 L30,20 25,25 25,5z" /> 
  
  <path d="M30,20 L60,20 55,25 25,25" />
  
  <path d="M60,20 L60,40 55,35 55,25" /> 
  
  <path d="M60,40 L0,40 5,35 55,35z" />
           
  <path d="M0,40 L0,0 5,5 5,35z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Please mind that this works with this kind of shapes. For a shape with several "turning points" and in different position it won't work.

UPDATE

1. I un clutter your code. Since all lines have the same `stroke-linecap` I'm putting it in the SVG. Also I'm moving the `stroke-width` in the JavaScript since I need it there.
2. In the Javascript I define the lines array `linesRy`. For every line I'm getting the value of the x1 and y1 attributes.
3. Using the value of the values for the x1 and y1 attributes of every line and the `stroke-width` I'm drawing a pink `rect` in every corner.

The OP updated the question posting some code. I am updating my code too:

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

let strokeWidth = 4

let linesRy = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("line"));

linesRy.forEach((l)=>{
  l.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", strokeWidth);
  let x = l.getAttribute("x1");
  let y = l.getAttribute("y1");
  
  drawRect({
    x:x-strokeWidth/2,
    y:y-strokeWidth/2,
    width:strokeWidth,
    height:strokeWidth,
    class:"pink"
  }, SvgjsG1008);
})


function drawRect(o, parent) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "rect");
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}
```

```css
line{
stroke-linecap:square;
}

.pink{fill:pink}
```

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="700" height="400" viewBox="-100 -20 350 200">
<g id="SvgjsG1008" transform="matrix(2.5,0,0,2.5,0,0)"><line id="SvgjsLine1009" x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0"  stroke="#ffdc0b" ></line>
  
<line id="SvgjsLine1010" x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="20" stroke="#002438"></line>

<line id="SvgjsLine1011" x1="30" y1="20" x2="60" y2="20" stroke="#9b56bb"></line>
  
<line id="SvgjsLine1012" x1="60" y1="20" x2="60" y2="40" stroke="#c6c7e2"></line>
   
<line id="SvgjsLine1013" x1="60" y1="40" x2="0" y2="40"  stroke="#318700" ></line>

<line id="SvgjsLine1014" x1="0" y1="40" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="#fe854f" ></line>
  
  
  
<!--  
<rect width="5" height="5" x="30" y="0"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="30" y="20"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="60" y="20"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="60" y="40"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="0" y="40"></rect>
<rect width="5" height="5" x="0" y="0"></rect>-->

</g></svg>
```

Comment: Instead of paths, I am trying with lines. When I take the bbox and place the rectangles. They don't get placed at exact positions. I have added stroke-width to lines for them to appear thick. How can I get them position right ?

Comment: It is at the rectangles the mouse interactions should happen like one layer over the other and vise versa..Even the mitre effect.

Comment: I have added the sample code in the question. Please have a look @enxaneta

Comment: Great,  I think that would solve as I was wrong with math calculation of x:x-strokeWidth/2, y:y-strokeWidth/2 instead I used the same x & y. I would see now on mouse clicks of rect how could I change its colors taking it from adjacent lines to make it look as a same line without rect.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. In this case please consider accepting my answer

Comment: Partially it did do. But I need to think about mitre effect in this.

Comment: You won't get the mitre effect you want with lines and you know that.

Comment: I don't know with the mitre effect. I thought I can modify the rectangle and get.Should I use paths for that ?

Comment: How do you think I could achieve it.With lines ,paths or just polygon points ??. What can I do for a shape with several "turning points" and in different positions?